# Node js cheerio parsing html

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, cheerio

So I have a problem where I can't get the link to a movie I wanna scrape for the "People also liked" section where it shows you movies that are similar. I can't get too that page on some movies though because there is a character section

```
function findCommonMovies(movie, callback){

    request('http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q='+ movie +'&s=all', function (error, response, body) {
      if (error){
          return
      }else{
          var $ = cheerio.load(body);
          var title = $(".result_text").first().text().split("(")[0].split(" ").join('')
          var commonMovies = []
          var endurl = $(".findSection .findList .findResult .result_text a").attr("href")
          var test
          request('http://www.imdb.com' + endurl, function (err, response, body) {

              if (err){
                  console.log(err)
              }else{
                  var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                  $(".rec_page .rec_item a img").each(function(){
                    var title = $(this).attr("title")
                    commonMovies.push(title)
                  });
              }
              callback(commonMovies)
          });
      }
    });

}
findCommonMovies("Lucifer", function(common){
  console.log(common)
})
```

will print out an empty array

```
findCommonMovies("Lucifer", function(common){
  console.log(common)
})
```

will print out an array with data inside

```
findCommonMovies("Gotham", function(common){
  console.log(common)
})
```

[Lucifer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvH1Y.png)

[Gotham](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjict.png)

http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=Lucifer&s=all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a a tag like this with name "tt" `<a name="tt"></a>`
You can use this selector to get the desired section tag

```
var endurl = $('a[name=tt]').parent().parent().find(".findSection .findList .findResult .result_text a").attr("href");
```

Comment: I don't understand how I would use this to get to my tag

Comment: Check out my latest edit and replace your endurl variable with the new one.